# can't make locate db on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, locate

I failed to use locate command in Mac Terminal. Here is my situation:

1. I have already run

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`

2. Logs when run as user:

`./locate.mklocatedb
^Clocate.mklocatedb: cannot build locate database 
rmdir: /var/folders/sh/nzqq8z612bz1k1nt7k0jr6680000gn/T//mklocatet0qA6zDDUe:
 No such file or directory`

3. Logs when run as root:

`sudo -s ./locate.mklocatedb

Password: 
^Clocate.mklocatedb: cannot build locate database rmdir: /tmp/mklocateIMIB7Z4JDM: No such file or directory`

4. the /etc/locate.rc is unchanged.
5. env $LOCATE_CONFIG is not set yet.

PS: the reason I press `Ctrl + c` to terminal the `locate.mklocatedb` is:
there isn't a circle running at the right-top of current Terminal Tab anymore.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Workaround! `locate`  is actually not popular on Mac, cause it's has a good replacement -> mdfind, in which u can choose what to index, including app, contact, filenames.etc.